# can not crop thumbnail of passed size

Tags: php

I have an image whose size is "300X367" .

I have an image function which crop thumbnail by using this type

but this function crop thumbnail of "41X50". I think it crop thumbnail by scale of original image.

But I want accurate thumbnail size of passing parameter. I can't put code here of image.php as the size is too big.

If anyone have solution for passing size parameter in image tag & crop thumbnail. please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code

```
    <?php
    function getFileExtenction($image)
    {
        $imageAry = explode(".", $image);
        return $imageAry[1];
    }

    $image = 'images/imageName.png'; //Your image location

    $imageType = getFileExtenction($image); //check the image file type

    if ($imageType == "png")
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($image);

    else if ($imageType == "jpg")
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

    else if ($imageType == "gif")
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    else
    {

    }

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image); //To get the image width and height

    $newwidth = 41; //Give your thumbanail image width 
    $newheight = 50; //Give your thubnail  image height
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);


    $filename = "NewImagename." . $imageType; 

    /*========== if you want to store this file in a folder Ex: "thumbs" ==========
    $filename = "thumbs/NewImagename." . $imageType; 
    */

    imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);

    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    ?>
```